# Why the Alamofire compile errors?

Tags: xcode, alamofire

To fix the errors Xcode flags, I figured I could fork the Alamofire repository and manually update the files on my machine, and then have my Xcode project's podfile file refer to my forked version of Alamofire instead of the regular version. But I can't seem to locate some of the files that Xcode flags. How should I proceed? Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using an old version of Alamofire. You should be running 4.9.1 or newer to fix any compiler issues.